# Merge multiple byte arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, array-merge

I want to merge multiple byte arrays but failing.The final array shows the last added byte array only, not all byte arrays. Following is my try.

```
List<byte[]> d = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (var item in IDs)
{       
    obj = RequisitionsObj.GenerateLabOrderReq();

    if (obj.Data != null)
    {    
        d.Add(obj.Data);              
    }     
}

byte[] final = Combine(d.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray());

private byte[] Combine(params byte[][] arrays)
{
    byte[] rv = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
    int offset = 0;

    foreach (byte[] array in arrays)
    {
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, rv, offset, array.Length);
        offset += array.Length;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `Combine` method. Just use `SelectMany`:

```
List<byte[]> d = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (var item in IDs)
{ 
    obj = RequisitionsObj.GenerateLabOrderReq();
    if (obj.Data != null)
    {    
        d.Add(obj.Data);
    }

}

byte[] final = d.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

A working sample:

```
List<byte[]> d = new List<byte[]>();
byte[] b1 = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
byte[] b2 = new byte[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
d.Add(b1);
d.Add(b2);
byte[] b3 = d.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray(); // Content is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: I just tried it out with a sample (see my edit) and it worked as expected. There must be something else happening in your code